# Can't define a Map object in Map/Reduce script?

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript2.0

```
ReferenceError: "Map" is not defined.
```

I'm trying to create a Map object in a Map/Reduce script but apparently is undefined in SuiteScript Map/Reduce.

I'm defining the map the same way it's defined in JS, I've tried the same line of code in a Client Script (SS 1.0) and it worked, does this have anything to do with the fact that it's a Map/Reduce script so there'd be an alternative for a Map object?

```
try{
            
              var myMap = new Map();
              log.debug('myMap',myMap);
              var val1 = searchresult[0].getValue('id1');
              var val2 = searchresult[1].getValue('id2');
              myMap.set(val1, val2);
              log.debug('myMap - set',myMap);
        }
        catch(e){
            log.error('error',e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` is an ES6+ feature. Make sure your Map/Reduce is targeting SuiteScript 2.1.